# How to exclude commons logging dependency of spring with ivy?

Tags: dependencies, slf4j, ivy, apache-commons-logging

I have a project build with ant using ivy for dependency management. I have no ivysetting file, but an `ivy.xml` with the following dependency (I want to use spring with slf4j instead of commons logging):

```
<configurations>
  <conf name="compile" />
  <conf name="runtime" extends="compile"/>
</configurations>
<dependencies>
  <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-webmvc" rev="3.0.5.RELEASE" conf="compile->default">
    <exclude org="commons-logging" name="commons-logging"/>
  </dependency>
  <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.6.1" conf="compile->default" />
  <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="jcl-over-slf4j" rev="1.6.1" conf="runtime->default" />
</dependencies>
```

But when resolving the compile configuration, `commons-logging` is resolved. I also tried to use the exclude on an explicit `spring-core` dependency but `commons-logging` is always placed into the compile classpath.

What is my fault? Isn't it that what [Not Using Commons Logging](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#d0e767) describes for maven? Is it an ivy bug? Need I a special setting? Has ivy something cached? Any idea?

I use ant 1.8.2 and ivy 2.2.0, Using IvyDE in Eclipse has the same problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your usage of the `<exclude />` seems to be broken for unkown reasons. I tried something similar on my pc and the following worked:
Try [the top-level exclude](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/exclude.html) (which is directly under `<dependencies />`:

```
    <dependencies>
      <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-webmvc" rev="3.0.5.RELEASE" conf="compile->default">
      </dependency>
      <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.6.1" conf="compile->default" />
      <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="jcl-over-slf4j" rev="1.6.1" conf="runtime->default" />
      <exclude org="commons-logging"/>
</dependencies>
```

I don't know why the other one is not working. There are some bugs in JIRA concerning exclude and circular dependencies, but that doesn't seem to fit this case. Maybe it's a real bug.

Comment: No, I see commons-logging in the report - and have a look in the [maven repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging) (which is in the default resolver as ibiblio, no own ivy repository)

Comment: Note that the <exclude> tag comes at the end of the dependencies. For me, it was not possible to add it on any other place within dependencies but in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Use module instead of name

`<exclude org="commons-logging" module="commons-logging"/>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<exclude name="commons-logging"/>
```

put above as general exclude might work better for you.